# Spring JPA query returns List<PageImpl>, when the repository return type is List<Post>

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

From what I understand, this should not be possible in the first place. A generic is supposed to prevent this from happening. When I try to access the list, I get an InvocationTargetException (probably since it expects Post). This is the relevant section from my code:

```
List<Post> posts;

Sort sort = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "dateCreate"));
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageIndex, pageSize, sort);

posts = postRepository.findAll(pageable);
```

This is the function in my repository:

```
List<Post> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The list that is actually returned contains one `PageImpl`, and the `PageImpl` contains the `List<Post>` that was supposed to be returned in the first place.

Comment: An InvocationTargetException wraps another Exception. When you ask a question and your code is getting an Exception *alway* post the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
Page<Post> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

And convert it to list:

```
List<Post> postList =  x.findAll(page).getContent();
```